# Problem importing getters into Router - Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Problem importing getters into Rotate - Vuex.

I am trying to import a value that is within the vuex state.

An error is reported, stating that it is undefined.

I have no idea what I might have done wrong. Please, if anyone can help, I will be very grateful.

Thanks for listening

Error 
TypeError: "_store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.getters is undefined"

Store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './module-auth'

Vue.use(Vuex)
export default function () {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      auth
    },
    strict: process.env.DEV
  })
  return Store
}
```

module-auth
Getters

```
import decode from 'jwt-decode'

function isTokenExpired (state) {
  try {
    const decoded = decode(state.token)
    if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
      return true
    } else return false
  } catch (err) {
    return false
  }
}
export {
  isTokenExpired,
}
```

Router

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default function () {
  const Router = new VueRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
    routes,
    mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
    base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
  })

  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const publicPages = ['/']
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path)

    const loggedIn = store.getters['auth/isTokenExpired']
    console.log(loggedIn)

    if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
      return next('/')
    }
    next()
  })
  return Router
}
```

Comment: your code seems good. Mistake may be in other places. Check the store imported is really the store variable, structure of files, etc..

Comment: Thanks for listening.

I think I found the problem.

I need to instantiate a function, not an object.

It worked.

store().getters['auth/isTokenExpired']

Is correct?

Comment: An object, not a function :)

Comment: I can not load this object into the index route.

The error is displayed. =( . store.getters['auth/isTokenExpired'] - Undefined

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you try to use a function as Vuex module.
Module should be an object.
[Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) say:

```js
export const moduleA = {
  state: { count: 0 },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    }
  },

  getters: {
    doubleCount(state) {
      return state.count * 2;
    }
  }
};
```

And your function `isTokenExpired` looks like it should be placed in "getters" section.

Comment: It looks like he know that and share only the getter part of the module.

Comment: Error TypeError: "_store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.getters is undefined"

Then I have no idea why he has that error. The code he provided clearly shows the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for listening.

I think I found the problem.

I need to instantiate a function, not an object.

It worked.

store().getters['auth/isTokenExpired']

Is correct?

Comment: store.getters.something is correct. But for that you list export the store object created with new Store()

Comment: If you post all used files we can see better what is the problem. Also, creating a minimal bugged example is a pain but the better way to learn and find the problem source.

Comment: Since you want one store onstance to be reused anywhere in your app, you need to export an object instead of a function, then use an object. If not, you will crea

Comment: I can not load this object into the index route.

The error is displayed. =( . store.getters['auth/isTokenExpired'] - Undefined

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a function that create a store and use it as a function will create many stores and is not desired.

Since you need to use one instance of store anywhere, you need to export the store instance, not a function that create a store.

Comment: I can not load this object into the index route.

The error is displayed. =( . store.getters['auth/isTokenExpired'] - Undefined

Comment: yes, you can. Please share a repo to continue investigating